# Copy listitem from one site to another

Tags: wss-3.0, workflow

We have a site with H&S incidents and depending on the division it should get copied/updated to its respective divisional site.

I've created work flows with sharepoint designer and managed to do this for lists in the same site but I don't get the option as part of the wizard to transfer to a different destination site.  Is this possible at all?

thanks

Comment: If you wan't to proceed manually, there's always this option : http://goo.gl/VpSLZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot copy list items to another site with OOTB SharePoint Designer activities. If you have server access you can try [this extended activity](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home) that can be used to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks Toni - surprised i didn't find that myself during my searches.  I've put this on my test site and it works like a charm.  Cheers

Comment: Cool, good to know!